# Does newtons method run 40 times?

Tags: scheme

The following is code that I wrote for newtons method:

```
(define (newtons-method f guess n)
(define (newtons-method-h guess k)
 (if(= k n)
    guess
    (let ((next (- guess (/ (f guess) ((der f 0.1) guess)))))
    (newtons-method-h next (+ k 1)))))
(newtons-method-h guess 0))
```

As well as code that I wrote to find square roots of numbers using newton's method:

```
 (define (sqrt-newt n)
 (newtons-method (lambda (x) (- (* x x) n)) 1.0 40))
```

I am wondering... Does sqrt-newt call newtons-method for 40 interations? I believe the answer is yes, but I am drawing a blank here.

Comment: Add a print statement to `newtons-method`, run the code above, count the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a counter to you code:

```
(define counter null) ; define a global variable

(define (newtons-method f guess n)
  (define (newtons-method-h guess k)
    (set! counter (add1 counter)) ; increment it at each call
    (if (= k n)
        guess
        (let ((next (- guess (/ (f guess) ((der f 0.1) guess)))))
          (newtons-method-h next (+ k 1)))))
  (set! counter 0) ; initialize it before starting
  (newtons-method-h guess 0))

(sqrt-newt 2) ; run the procedure
=> 1.4142135623730951
counter ; check the counter's value
=> 41
```

As you can see, the `newtons-method-h` procedure got called 41 times - one more than you expected, because the procedure gets invoked one last time when `(= k n)` and that's when the recursion ends.